# Unity - Scene Additive Not showing in final Build

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, scene-manager

so I'm having a problem.

I'm developing a game for our final project and I'm using scene load additive to load all the scenes). So the problem is... Everything works right when I test/play the game through the editor, all scenes are load as expected with a SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync(sceneIndex, LoadSceneMode.Additive). But when I create a build, the supposed scene that should be loaded with LoadSceneAsycn doesn't show up...

I'll try to leave here some of the code used and I'll try to explain the logic

When I load the first level I'll also load the next scenes, to this purpose I've created a script that will select which scene should load next:

```
private void Start() {
    switch (goToScene) {
        case GoToScene.LABORATORY:
            GameManager.ForceAsyncLoad(2);
            break;
        case GoToScene.GARAGE:
            GameManager.ForceAsyncLoad(3);
            break;
    }
}
```

Then It will call the method ForceAsyncLoad from my GameManager which is a Coroutine:

```
IEnumerator LoadAsync(int sceneIndex) {
   AsyncOperation operation = SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync(sceneIndex, LoadSceneMode.Additive);

     while (!operation.isDone) {
         yield return null;
     }

     SceneManager.SetActiveScene(SceneManager.GetSceneByBuildIndex(sceneIndex));

     Debug.Log("Scene Additive Load Completed");

}
```

Ok so far... This is all I'll do to load the scene additive, but for some reason on the Editor this works as expected but when I create a build it won't load.

Also, the scenes when loaded have almost all objects disabled, only one or two game objects will be active. One of them is a trigger when the character goes through it, it will enable the objects in that scene.

I'll leave here my last build log:

```
Mono path[0] = 'D:/UnityFinishedGames/TBA-Master-D/BetaVersion/TBA-MasterD_Data/Managed'
Mono config path = 'D:/UnityFinishedGames/TBA-Master-D/BetaVersion/MonoBleedingEdge/etc'
PlayerConnection initialized from D:/UnityFinishedGames/TBA-Master-D/BetaVersion/TBA-MasterD_Data (debug = 0)
PlayerConnection initialized network socket : 0.0.0.0 55357
Multi-casting "[IP] 192.168.1.67 [Port] 55357 [Flags] 2 [Guid] 839978317 [EditorId] 2132102930 [Version] 1048832 [Id] WindowsPlayer(DESKTOP-H2EGAS4) [Debug] 1 [PackageName] WindowsPlayer [ProjectName] TBA-MasterD" to [225.0.0.222:54997]...
Started listening to [0.0.0.0:55357]
Starting managed debugger on port 56317
Using monoOptions --debugger-agent=transport=dt_socket,embedding=1,server=y,suspend=n,address=0.0.0.0:56317
PlayerConnection already initialized - listening to [0.0.0.0:55357]
Initialize engine version: 2019.4.16f1 (e05b6e02d63e)
[Subsystems] Discovering subsystems at path D:/UnityFinishedGames/TBA-Master-D/BetaVersion/TBA-MasterD_Data/UnitySubsystems
GfxDevice: creating device client; threaded=1
Direct3D:
    Version:  Direct3D 11.0 [level 11.1]
    Renderer: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1070 (ID=0x1b81)
    Vendor:   (null)
    VRAM:     3072 MB
    Driver:   30.0.14.7141
Begin MonoManager ReloadAssembly
- Completed reload, in  0.342 seconds
D3D11 device created for Microsoft Media Foundation video decoding.
<RI> Initializing input.

<RI> Input initialized.

<RI> Initialized touch support.

UnloadTime: 0.657200 ms
Unloading 6 Unused Serialized files (Serialized files now loaded: 0)
UnloadTime: 52.699800 ms
System memory in use before: 215.6 MB.
System memory in use after: 189.3 MB.

Unloading 29 unused Assets to reduce memory usage. Loaded Objects now: 11007.
Total: 51.210800 ms (FindLiveObjects: 0.710300 ms CreateObjectMapping: 0.140200 ms MarkObjects: 49.202300 ms  DeleteObjects: 1.157200 ms)

The referenced script on this Behaviour (Game Object 'ExitAndTopLevelStairs') is missing! 
(Filename: C:\buildslave\unity\build\Runtime/Mono/ManagedMonoBehaviourRef.cpp Line: 334)

Saving Game...
UnityEngine.DebugLogHandler:Internal_Log(LogType, LogOption, String, Object)
UnityEngine.DebugLogHandler:LogFormat(LogType, Object, String, Object[])
UnityEngine.Logger:Log(LogType, Object)
UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
SaveSystemManager:SaveGame(Checkpoint, List`1) (at D:\GitHub\MasterD_FinalProject\TBA-MasterD\Assets\Scripts\SaveSystem\SaveSystemManager.cs:64)
SaveSystemManager:Save(Checkpoint, List`1) (at D:\GitHub\MasterD_FinalProject\TBA-MasterD\Assets\Scripts\SaveSystem\SaveSystemManager.cs:112)
Checkpoint:OnTriggerEnter(Collider) (at D:\GitHub\MasterD_FinalProject\TBA-MasterD\Assets\Scripts\SaveSystem\Checkpoint.cs:29)
 
(Filename: D:/GitHub/MasterD_FinalProject/TBA-MasterD/Assets/Scripts/SaveSystem/SaveSystemManager.cs Line: 64)

You can now use the drone by pressing the key: 'Q'
UnityEngine.DebugLogHandler:Internal_Log(LogType, LogOption, String, Object)
UnityEngine.DebugLogHandler:LogFormat(LogType, Object, String, Object[])
UnityEngine.Logger:Log(LogType, Object)
UnityEngine.Debug:LogWarning(Object)
charController:SetDroneControl(Boolean) (at D:\GitHub\MasterD_FinalProject\TBA-MasterD\Assets\Scripts\Tiago\player\charController.cs:381)
ItemGiver:Update() (at D:\GitHub\MasterD_FinalProject\TBA-MasterD\Assets\Scripts\Jorge\ItemGiver.cs:19)
 
(Filename: D:/GitHub/MasterD_FinalProject/TBA-MasterD/Assets/Scripts/Tiago/player/charController.cs Line: 381)

Keys to interact: Space, to go UP and, LeftControl, to go down.
UnityEngine.DebugLogHandler:Internal_Log(LogType, LogOption, String, Object)
UnityEngine.DebugLogHandler:LogFormat(LogType, Object, String, Object[])
UnityEngine.Logger:Log(LogType, Object)
UnityEngine.Debug:LogWarning(Object)
DroneController:OnEnable() (at D:\GitHub\MasterD_FinalProject\TBA-MasterD\Assets\Scripts\Fabio\Drone\DroneController.cs:190)
UnityEngine.GameObject:SetActive(Boolean)
charController:DroneControl() (at D:\GitHub\MasterD_FinalProject\TBA-MasterD\Assets\Scripts\Tiago\player\charController.cs:346)
charController:Update() (at D:\GitHub\MasterD_FinalProject\TBA-MasterD\Assets\Scripts\Tiago\player\charController.cs:176)
 
(Filename: D:/GitHub/MasterD_FinalProject/TBA-MasterD/Assets/Scripts/Fabio/Drone/DroneController.cs Line: 190)

DRONE::: Vent_Exit_Mesh ( View to PIT room ) (2) (VentController)
UnityEngine.DebugLogHandler:Internal_Log(LogType, LogOption, String, Object)
UnityEngine.DebugLogHandler:LogFormat(LogType, Object, String, Object[])
UnityEngine.Logger:Log(LogType, Object)
UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
DroneController:Shoot() (at D:\GitHub\MasterD_FinalProject\TBA-MasterD\Assets\Scripts\Fabio\Drone\DroneController.cs:156)
DroneController:Update() (at D:\GitHub\MasterD_FinalProject\TBA-MasterD\Assets\Scripts\Fabio\Drone\DroneController.cs:88)
 
(Filename: D:/GitHub/MasterD_FinalProject/TBA-MasterD/Assets/Scripts/Fabio/Drone/DroneController.cs Line: 156)

DRONE::: Vent_Exit_Mesh (Entrance From Drone Room) (1) (VentController)
UnityEngine.DebugLogHandler:Internal_Log(LogType, LogOption, String, Object)
UnityEngine.DebugLogHandler:LogFormat(LogType, Object, String, Object[])
UnityEngine.Logger:Log(LogType, Object)
UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
DroneController:Shoot() (at D:\GitHub\MasterD_FinalProject\TBA-MasterD\Assets\Scripts\Fabio\Drone\DroneController.cs:156)
DroneController:Update() (at D:\GitHub\MasterD_FinalProject\TBA-MasterD\Assets\Scripts\Fabio\Drone\DroneController.cs:88)
 
(Filename: D:/GitHub/MasterD_FinalProject/TBA-MasterD/Assets/Scripts/Fabio/Drone/DroneController.cs Line: 156)

DRONE::: ControlMachine (DoorManager)
UnityEngine.DebugLogHandler:Internal_Log(LogType, LogOption, String, Object)
UnityEngine.DebugLogHandler:LogFormat(LogType, Object, String, Object[])
UnityEngine.Logger:Log(LogType, Object)
UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
DroneController:Shoot() (at D:\GitHub\MasterD_FinalProject\TBA-MasterD\Assets\Scripts\Fabio\Drone\DroneController.cs:156)
DroneController:Update() (at D:\GitHub\MasterD_FinalProject\TBA-MasterD\Assets\Scripts\Fabio\Drone\DroneController.cs:88)
 
(Filename: D:/GitHub/MasterD_FinalProject/TBA-MasterD/Assets/Scripts/Fabio/Drone/DroneController.cs Line: 156)

On the next trigger enter is to Disable Objects? False
UnityEngine.DebugLogHandler:Internal_Log(LogType, LogOption, String, Object)
UnityEngine.DebugLogHandler:LogFormat(LogType, Object, String, Object[])
UnityEngine.Logger:Log(LogType, Object)
UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
SceneSwitcher:ToogleTypeOfSwitch() (at D:\GitHub\MasterD_FinalProject\TBA-MasterD\Assets\Scripts\InGameSceneManager\SceneSwitcher.cs:66)
<DisableAllObjectsAsync>d__5:MoveNext() (at D:\GitHub\MasterD_FinalProject\TBA-MasterD\Assets\Scripts\InGameSceneManager\SceneController.cs:91)
UnityEngine.SetupCoroutine:InvokeMoveNext(IEnumerator, IntPtr)
 
(Filename: D:/GitHub/MasterD_FinalProject/TBA-MasterD/Assets/Scripts/InGameSceneManager/SceneSwitcher.cs Line: 66)

Lista para Parar: 15
UnityEngine.DebugLogHandler:Internal_Log(LogType, LogOption, String, Object)
UnityEngine.DebugLogHandler:LogFormat(LogType, Object, String, Object[])
UnityEngine.Logger:Log(LogType, Object)
UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
GameManager:PauseAllAudioSources() (at D:\GitHub\MasterD_FinalProject\TBA-MasterD\Assets\Scripts\GameManager.cs:263)
GameManager:_SetPauseGame() (at D:\GitHub\MasterD_FinalProject\TBA-MasterD\Assets\Scripts\GameManager.cs:303)
GameManager:SetPause() (at D:\GitHub\MasterD_FinalProject\TBA-MasterD\Assets\Scripts\GameManager.cs:107)
charController:Update() (at D:\GitHub\MasterD_FinalProject\TBA-MasterD\Assets\Scripts\Tiago\player\charController.cs:140)
 
(Filename: D:/GitHub/MasterD_FinalProject/TBA-MasterD/Assets/Scripts/GameManager.cs Line: 263)

Game Manager: Game Paused
UnityEngine.DebugLogHandler:Internal_Log(LogType, LogOption, String, Object)
UnityEngine.DebugLogHandler:LogFormat(LogType, Object, String, Object[])
UnityEngine.Logger:Log(LogType, Object)
UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
GameManager:_SetPauseGame() (at D:\GitHub\MasterD_FinalProject\TBA-MasterD\Assets\Scripts\GameManager.cs:308)
GameManager:SetPause() (at D:\GitHub\MasterD_FinalProject\TBA-MasterD\Assets\Scripts\GameManager.cs:107)
charController:Update() (at D:\GitHub\MasterD_FinalProject\TBA-MasterD\Assets\Scripts\Tiago\player\charController.cs:140)
 
(Filename: D:/GitHub/MasterD_FinalProject/TBA-MasterD/Assets/Scripts/GameManager.cs Line: 308)

Unloading 6 Unused Serialized files (Serialized files now loaded: 0)
UnloadTime: 36.279700 ms
Loading Game...
UnityEngine.DebugLogHandler:Internal_Log(LogType, LogOption, String, Object)
UnityEngine.DebugLogHandler:LogFormat(LogType, Object, String, Object[])
UnityEngine.Logger:Log(LogType, Object)
UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
SaveSystemManager:LoadGameData() (at D:\GitHub\MasterD_FinalProject\TBA-MasterD\Assets\Scripts\SaveSystem\SaveSystemManager.cs:80)
SaveSystemManager:LoadData() (at D:\GitHub\MasterD_FinalProject\TBA-MasterD\Assets\Scripts\SaveSystem\SaveSystemManager.cs:123)
<LoadAsync>d__51:MoveNext() (at D:\GitHub\MasterD_FinalProject\TBA-MasterD\Assets\Scripts\GameManager.cs:380)
UnityEngine.SetupCoroutine:InvokeMoveNext(IEnumerator, IntPtr)
 
(Filename: D:/GitHub/MasterD_FinalProject/TBA-MasterD/Assets/Scripts/SaveSystem/SaveSystemManager.cs Line: 80)

System memory in use before: 337.6 MB.
System memory in use after: 220.4 MB.

Unloading 559 unused Assets to reduce memory usage. Loaded Objects now: 11042.
Total: 46.406900 ms (FindLiveObjects: 0.465700 ms CreateObjectMapping: 0.138900 ms MarkObjects: 27.467400 ms  DeleteObjects: 18.334200 ms)

The referenced script on this Behaviour (Game Object 'ExitAndTopLevelStairs') is missing! 
(Filename: C:\buildslave\unity\build\Runtime/Mono/ManagedMonoBehaviourRef.cpp Line: 334)

Setting up 4 worker threads for Enlighten.
  Thread -> id: 5130 -> priority: 1 
  Thread -> id: fa0 -> priority: 1 
  Thread -> id: b32c -> priority: 1 
  Thread -> id: 8f30 -> priority: 1 
##utp:{"type":"MemoryLeaks","version":2,"phase":"Immediate","time":1633874119606,"processId":39884,"allocatedMemory":709939,"memoryLabels":[{"Permanent":24},{"NewDelete":220},{"Thread":68},{"Manager":2244},{"GfxThread":24},{"Physics":32},{"Serialization":24},{"String":151},{"DynamicArray":572712},{"HashMap":3072},{"PoolAlloc":32},{"Sprites":32},{"GI":130672},{"VR":1132},{"Subsystems":4294966796}]}
```

I also have added the scenes to the buildIndex so

[Build Settings | Scenes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BoFP3.png)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I found out what was the problem. So I used a For loop to iterate through all objects that had a specific Script (yap.. heavy CPU...) so, the way I've used the search would find me just one object and would break the for. This worked properly in the editor because of the way the hierarchy was set... when building the game there's no hierarchy copy so... yeah that was the problem !!